# BLE chip antenna matching

Tags: antenna, bluetooth-low-energy

Hi I'm using a BLE module connected to a chip antenna, the antenna manufacture establishes the path width is .4mm, if I need to match the network to 50ohm how can I do it? the system has a pi-match C1=0.8pF L=3.9nH and C2 is 0.8pF how can I make sure it matches 50 ohms?

Comment: VNA(vector network analyzer) does exactly this work. Tuning is not a simple process. You can simulate(ansys workbench-) your PCB. But dont forget even plastic enclosure which cover your PCB may effect the final impedance. There are common formulations. You can select values and width acc to your PCB material and frequency if you cant access VNA.

Comment: You can also ask the PCB manufacturer to do the matching.

Answer (score 1):

This calls for quite a specific and expensive piece of equipment, the VNA, as already commented. However, for a start you could start to design correctly the board.

First of all the .4mm trace width is bogus, because it depends on the kind of substrate and board thickness. *It is* correct for a 1.6mm FR4 double side board, however, probably that was the intention of the manufacturer.

You need to have the shortest track possible, with the matching components as directed in the reference layout and ground both under the trace and at the sides *at a specified distance*. This makes a stripline and the distance from the ground and the trace (on the three sides) determines the impedance.

The formulas are quite horrible, sincerely. Usually they put them in the modules instruction, I got mine from the proteus iii reference manual (a BLE module), there are about 3 pages on how to do that connection.

When you have done most probably it will be working altough maybe not at maximum efficiency. With a VNA it will be possible to tune the matching component to the effective layout (the VNA technician knows the detail).